# Getting Wordpress to interpret permissions for scheduled posts the same as with published posts

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress, there's a number of role permissions who's functions change the moment a post is published. These can effect whether or not a contributor can edit, or even delete one of those posts.

I need to change it so that the these permissions change behavior as soon as a scheduled publication-time is set -- rather than the moment of publication.

Is there an easy-to-understand way to do this? (By "easy-to-understand" I mean that cryptic explanations how to do something that will confuse and possibly require a ton of delicate development might not be sufficient.)

If the solution involves a plug-in, the requirements are that the plugin be *current* and well-rated.

Comment: I am not clear on what it is that changes when a post gets published? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Juan Not to be off-putting --- but if you have to ask that question - you probably don't know the answer to _my_ question.  ------ Nonetheless - in answer to your question - an example is -- contributors (by default) can not edit or delete their own posts after they are published. However, they _can_ do this for posts that are _scheduled_ for publication at a future date.

Comment: You are not being off-putting, in the worse case you just lost a chance for solving your problem.